# ReCaptcha.scala.scala:114: not found: value compact

Tags: scala, lift, recaptcha

I have the following code:

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/ReCaptcha

and compile the project(sbt), send me the following message:

src/main/scala/code/model/ReCaptcha.scala.scala:114: not found: value compact

[error]     val RecaptchaOptions = compact(render(reCaptchaOptions))

any suggestions please :(

Comment: @Jean Then again, they are mostly Lift questions. Lift support on Stack Overflow is rather lacking, so it might just be that none of the questions have a valid answer. Unlikely, but possible.

Answer (score 2):

Compact comes from lift-json I would imagine as thats the only place I recall that method being defined. Try adding this import:

```
  import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
```

In addition, you may want to refer to the lift-json documentation for usage on compact(...)